# In-Memory DB for Entity Framework 4

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, in-memory-database

Does anyone know of a good in-memory DB that works well with .NET 4/EF 4? Specifically, I'm thinking of unit testing, such that each setup can easily create the DB, and populate it with default values, and each teardown can destroy it - in a quick fashion.

I've heard that SQLite [doesn't support .NET 4](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/2323.aspx) yet, and others have had trouble using it as a substitute for SQLServer (which is what the appliction will run on in release mode).

In the past, I used DevExpress XPO ORM and it had a built-in in-memory database that worked quite well for unit testing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing EF SQL Server based application with in-memory SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372030/testing-ef-sql-server-based-application-with-in-memory-sqlite)

Comment: @Craig Stuntz - I'm not looking to mock my repositories, that I can do now without trouble, I'm looking to substitute an in-memory DB for an actual one... so that I can not only test the services but I can test the code that generates the DB tables and inserts the default data into the DB.

Comment: To people who are reading this question, SQLite now supports .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 via this website: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Answer (score 8):

You'll have a problem unit testing with CE4 if your model has database-generated keys (usually specified in EF4 using the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] annotation), as CE4 doesn't support this.

But I found an easy workaround without needing to modify my production code (which runs on SQL 2008). I created a proxy sub-class of my DbContext, and in it overrode `OnModelCreating` to remove the annotation, and overrode `SaveChanges` to set the ID manually:

```
public class TestContext : MyDbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Id)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }

  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
    {
      entry.Entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

With these minor tweaks, I can now unit test the same repository code in CE4 that runs under SQL 2008 in production.

And if you are using integer IDs rather than GUIDs, there's a nice extension method here that can be plugged right into the above solution: http://enigmadomain.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/sql-compact-identity-columns-and-entity-framework/

Answer (score 2):

SQL CE will do this for you. It's an embedded database that runs in process. It works with EF4 (including Code First). The easiest way to get it is to directly install the NuGet package for it. There are two NuGet packages - one that just has SQL CE and the other that has the SQL CE that works with the EF Code First CTP4.

Comment: Yes, it does. Have a look at this post by Scott Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx.  The key here from that post is this section: "The SQL CE database engine then runs in-memory within your application.  When your application shuts down the database is automatically unloaded."

Comment: Not quite true, I have tested hosted a CE db on a ram disk, and there was about 50% improvement in query speed. CE still tends to hit the file system harder than it should (and what I expect).

Comment: Regardless of the # of times it may or may not hit the file system, does it not do *exactly* what @SnOrfus is seeking? Works well with EF4/.NET 4, quickly setup/tear down DB, workings with unit testing, easily populate seed data, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to un-mark this as the accepted answer. Ce and EF can be used together, but it is by no means a useful tool to unit test an EF model designed for Sql Server. Too many critical modifications need to be made to the EF model, such that you end up modelling for test environment, and not your production environment. Better EF support and an in-memory database is only in Ce 4 which is only CTP right now, and still has some problems that just make it not worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a problem for you to switch to EF CTP4 then it's like that:

EF4 CTP4
SQL CE 4 CTP

It will generate db in-memory for you as you write unit tests (code-first).